# Not able to connect to AWS Active MQ broker

Tags: python, stomp, amazon-mq

We are trying to connect to AWS Amazon MQ using python but facing an issue.
Please find below code and error.

code:

```
import stomp
#Establish a connection
con = stomp.Connection([('stomp+ssl://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mq.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com',61616)])
#listener class to be instantiated.
class Listener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)
    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print('received a message "%s"' % message)
con.set_listener('', Listener())
#wait will ensure it waits till connection is established and acknowledged.
# con.start()
con.connect('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', wait=True)
#subscribe to a particular topic or queue by giving the path and headers if required by the server.
con.subscribe('#', headers={})
```

Error:

```
Could not connect to host stomp+ssl://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mq.xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com, port 61616
Could not connect to host stomp+ssl://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mq.xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com, port 61616
Could not connect to host stomp+ssl://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mq.xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com, port 61616
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stomp_mqtt_subscribe.py", line 34, in <module>
    con.connect('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx', wait=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stomp/connect.py", line 150, in connect
    self.transport.start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stomp/transport.py", line 130, in start
    self.attempt_connection()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stomp/transport.py", line 834, in attempt_connection
    raise exception.ConnectFailedException()
stomp.exception.ConnectFailedException
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: no l left it as it was just for testing. We were trying to connect to it with telegraf plugin to fetch the data and it was successfully connected. But using python it didn't.

Comment: Did you address all the issues I identified in my answer? There were a handful of problems with your code.

Comment: did you find resolution to your problem @DhyaneshNaik

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use with stand-alone ActiveMQ Artemis, not AWS.  I also filter  message subscription on a selector field called "key".  Remove that selector from the headers if you want.  I'm using 30 second heartbeats here.

```
import stomp

def connect_and_subscribe(conn):
    conn.connect('username', 'p@$$w0rd', wait=True)
    conn.subscribe(destination='my-topic', id=12345, ack='auto', headers={'subscription-type': 'MULTICAST', 'selector': "key like '"+key+"'"})

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter=0

    def on_message(self, frame):
        self.counter+=1
        print('counter', self.counter)
        print('got:', frame)

    def on_disconnected(self):
        print('disconnected')
        connect_and_subscribe(self.conn)

key='test'
hosts = [('mqserver', 61616)]
conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=hosts, heartbeats=(30000, 30000))
conn.set_listener('', MyListener())
connect_and_subscribe(conn)
while True:
    pass
conn.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a handful of problems (and potential problems) with your code.

First, you're using this as the hostname:

```
stomp+ssl://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mq.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com
```

The `stomp+ssl://` should not be included in the hostname.

Second, you're using this as the port:

```
61616
```

By default the broker will not accept STOMP connection on port `61616`. You should likely use `61613` instead.

Third, you're subscribing to `#` which looks like something you might do with an MQTT client (although even that is [discouraged](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices/) with MQTT). The destination `#` has no special meaning in STOMP as the STOMP specification defines no wildcards. Your STOMP client will subscribe to a destination *literally* named `#` which is likely not what you want.